# Why OpenGL takes pointer to resource id when creating/releasing resource?

Tags: c++, opengl

I wonder why OpenGL takes pointer to resource id, because I'm doing something like this:

```
#include "OglResource.h"
#include <iostream>

void WINAPI DeleteVertexArray( GLuint item )
{
    glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &item);
}
OglResource MakeOglResource( GLenum type )
{
    switch( type )
    {
    case GL_VERTEX_SHADER:
        return OglResource(glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER), (OglResource::ReleaseFunc)glDeleteShader, GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        break;
    case GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER:
        return OglResource(glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER), (OglResource::ReleaseFunc)glDeleteShader, GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        break;
    case GL_VERTEX_ARRAY:
        {
            GLuint out = OglResource::INVALID_OGL_RESOURCE_ID;
            glGenVertexArrays(1, &out);
            return OglResource(out, DeleteVertexArray, GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
        }
        break;
    }

    return OglResource();
}
```

If the address of resource id I passed to OpenGL does matter, this is dangerous, because as soon as MakeOglResource function returns, the position I passed to OpenGL(&out) is invalid.

I tested this and it didn't seem like crashing the application, but I'm worried.

1. Why OpenGL wants me to pass address when CreateVertexArrays/DeleteVertexArrays?
2. Is this code looks safe to you?

Below is the implementation of OglResource:

```
#ifndef _HANDLE_H
#define _HANDLE_H

#include <memory>
#include <functional>

#define CALL_CONVENTION WINAPI
template <typename HANDLE_TYPE>
class Handle
{
public:
    typedef void (CALL_CONVENTION *ReleaseFunc)(HANDLE_TYPE);

private:
    // Handler
    std::shared_ptr<void> m_spItem;

public:
    operator HANDLE_TYPE()
    {
        return (HANDLE_TYPE)(m_spItem.get());
    }
    Handle( void )
        : m_spItem()
    {
    }
    Handle( HANDLE_TYPE id, ReleaseFunc fpRelease )
        : m_spItem(nullptr)
    {
        Reset(id,fpRelease);
    }
    void Reset( void )
    {
        m_spItem.reset();
    }
    void Reset( HANDLE_TYPE handle, ReleaseFunc fpRelease)
    {
        m_spItem.reset((void*)handle,[=](void* vpItem)
                                     {
                                        fpRelease((HANDLE_TYPE)vpItem);
                                     });
    }
};

#endif // _HANDLE_H

#ifndef _OGLRESOURCE_H
#define _OGLRESOURCE_H

#include <Windows.h>
#include <gl/glew.h>
#include <Gl/GL.h>
#include "Handle.h"

class OglResource : public Handle<GLuint>
{
    friend OglResource MakeOglResource( GLenum type );

public:
    GLenum m_type;
    OglResource( void )
        : Handle()
        , m_type(0)
    {
    }
    OglResource( GLuint resource, Handle::ReleaseFunc fpRelease, GLenum type )
        : Handle(resource, fpRelease)
        , m_type(type)

    {
    }
    enum { INVALID_OGL_RESOURCE_ID = 0 };
}; // class OglShader

OglResource MakeOglResource( GLenum type );

#endif // _OGLRESOURCE_H
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This interface allows the caller to generate or delete multiple resource ids (aka names) with a single call. I believe it's purely an efficiency consideration. If you passed by value, you would need one call for each id.

For example, this generates and deletes 3 ids:

```
GLuint ids[3];
glGenBuffers(3, ids);
glDeleteBuffers(3, ids);
```

You would otherwise need 3 calls each to generate and delete the 3 ids.

There is no requirement to pass the same pointer to `Gen` and `Delete`. The following is perfectly legal and safe:

```
GLuint id = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &id);
GLuint idCopy = id;
glDeleteBuffers(1, &idCopy);
```

Comment: If the reason you described is the sole purpose why the function needs pointer, I'm safe, I guess. Because of your answer, I noticed that my code is throwing away the ability of making multiple vao at the same time recklessly.. Thank you.